# Scenario on the sign of hooke's law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, harmonic-oscillator, spring

**Doubt is on the concept of the sign, not on the problem itself**

The main doubt is focused around the sign of $\vec{F}=-k\vec{x}$, and yes I've read a lot of posts on this page but it never ceases to be not be 100% clear, I know that the main thing is that it matters where you fix your reference system and your 0 of potential energy. So let's take this situation:

[image: Picture of the situation]

It is a simple pendulum attached to a spring in the x-direction with *small* oscillations (so that we can approximate trigonometric functions), it would make sense that when it's going to the right the sum of forces is: $$-\vec{F_{rest}}-\vec{T_x}=m\vec{a_x}$$ being $T_x$ the tension in the x-direction hence that it would be $$-(-kx)-T_x=ma_x$$ but it turns out it is $$-kx-T_x=ma_x$$ why?

Comment: what is $T_x$??

Comment: @JEB the x-component of the tension, it is written there, the 4th to last sentence

Comment: Right, but it has vector signs over it, and then it doesn't. Is it a function of $x$? And if so, does the sign match the spring's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hook's law as in $F = - k x$ is misleading because $x$ is not a displacement along some *x*-axis, as $F$ does not represent for along the same direction. Also, note that it is not a vector equation, so the direction for the law isn't specified, but only that $F$ has the *opposite* sense from $x$.

Remember that $x$ represents axial *extension* for the spring (ends moving apart by a measure of $x$ from equilibrium) and $F$ the *tensile* force of the spring (how much the ends are pushed apart).

The diagram above is missing some key pieces of information. A good FBD (Free Body Diagram) needs to show the directions of *positive* displacement for the displacement/angle variables in the system unless otherwise indicated.

[image: fig1]

I have chosen $\theta$ and $x$ for the two variables of the system, and indicate with arrows their positive directions. The angle is CCW (counter-clockwise) and the spring displacement is along the $-X$ direction (to the left).

This way $F_{\rm elastica} = - k x$ acts in the direction opposite of $x$

- When $x>0$ and the spring is extended, then $F_{\rm elastica}$ acts to the right, along the $+X$ direction (not shown above).
- When $x<0$ and the spring is compressed, then $F_{\rm elastica}$ acts to the left, along the $-X$ direction as shown in the diagram.

So here lies the discrepancy in the FBD that lead to your confusion in your question. The forces *are not* drawn in a positive sense and the displaced bob is shown *not* in a positive sense, at least where $x$ is concerned.

The root of the problem is that both $\theta$ and $x$ cannot be positive at the same time, as drawn. Had they drawn the bob such that it extends the springs (to the left) with positive $x$, and measured the angle $\theta$ from vertical in a CW (clock-wise) sense as positive, then everything would be consistent.

In any case, to establish the equations of motion, first, consider the kinematics between the variables

$$ x = -L \sin \theta $$

and then the force balance (positive => force to the right) of the bob

$$ -T \sin \theta -F_{\rm elastica} = m (-a_x) $$

Again, a positive angle $\theta$ causes a leftward tension from the rope and a leftward spring force as it is in compression. Also, note that acceleration $a_x$ is positive to the left (similar to $x$). Because the two conventions for positivity of $x$ and $a_x$ **have to be the same** I often designate acceleration with the same symbol as displacement but two dots over $a_x = \ddot{x}$

Usign $F_{\rm elastica} = - k x$ the equation of motion becomes

$$ -T \sin \theta + k x = -m \ddot{x} $$

which maintains the negative sense between the force and the displacement.

Now use the kinematic relationship $x=-L \sin \theta$ as well as its second derivative $\ddot{x} = -L \sin \ddot{\theta}$ to transform the equation above into a 1-DOF differential equation

$$ -T \sin \theta - k L \sin \theta = m L \sin \ddot{\theta} $$

which together with the force balance in the vertical direction, $T \cos \theta - P = m \ddot{y}$, completes the set. Here positive forces are along the $+Y$ direction.

Answer (score 4):

Be careful when writing in vector form. You don't have to care about signs in the vector form itself. $\vec F + \vec T = m \vec a$ must be the vectorial representation. (In 2d)

Since you've assumed the displacement to be positive, the vector $\vec F$ has a component $x$ equal to $-k(x)$ and not $-k(-x)$. An advice here would be to not think of these 2d vectors explicitly but think of components of these vectors. Do note that if you want to represent the vector in a diagram, it doesn't make sense to also include a negative sign to your vector since the negative sign in Hooke's law tells us that the force will be opposite to the displacement. You can either represent your force facing the $+x$ direction, and put a negative sign, or you can draw your vector towards the $-x$ and write the magnitude to be $+k(\Delta x)$.

Answer (score 1):

You really should think of the spring force as a restoring force with magnitude $F_S = k |\ell - \ell_0|$, expressing that its magnitude is proportional to the amount it has stretched from its unstretched length. The equation that you are writing down is actually $F_{Sx} = -k x$, meaning that, **on the specially chosen coordinate axis $x$ that points along the spring and has origin where the spring is unstretched**, the $x$-**component of the force** is given by that equation. In other words, using that coordinate system $x$ is the amount of stretch of the spring, and if you displace to the positive $x$ direction, the force points in the negative $x$ direction.

In your problem, if the spring is unstretched when the pendulum is down (it's not clear that is the case, but I guess it is assumed?), then you can place the $x$ origin at that location and Newton's Second law will give:
\begin{align}
\vec{F}_{\rm net} &= m \, \vec{a} \\
\vec{T} + \vec{F}_S + \vec{F}_g &= m \, \vec{a}\\
x:\quad T_x + F_{Sx} + F_{gx} &= m \, a_x \\
-T \, \sin\theta - k x + 0 &= m a_x
\end{align}